# google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 The provided Secret ID

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy the Django app to google cloud. Im following [this](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment#gcloud_5) tutorial from Google #Run the app on your local computer, I'm on the 4th step where I need to make migrations.
I'm using flexible environment

```
I receive this error: google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 The provided Secret ID [projects/618731075169/secrets/django_settings] does not match the expected format [[a-zA-Z_0-9]+]
```

I don't understand why since my service ID is correct:

```
secret_id = "projects/618731075169/secrets/django_settings/versions/latest"
```

and here is what the website looks like:

Secret: "django_settings"
projects/618731075169/secrets/django_settings

Any ideas of why this might be an issue?

Comment: stack overflow is dead... :)

Answer (score 1):

The `secret_id` in the Terraform code should not need most of that information.

```
secret_id = "django_settings"
```

Should work.